# Inline-block element gets pushed to next line

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm building a WordPress theme (was told by WP SE to bring this question here), but I have a problem with my footer widget area. All the widgets seem to layout properly with my CSS except the Recent Posts widget. It seems to double the margin-right of the previous element.

The widgets are sized to a width of 33% of their container. I'm giving the first two of three widgets on each row a right margin of 0.5% (33 * 3 + 0.5 * 2 = 100) and using an nth-child selector to give every third widget 0 right padding.

This works beautifully for most widgets as you can see in the first row on the live site. On the second row, I included the Recent Posts widget as the second element. This introduces the additional margin to the right of the preceding element.

You can see that Chrome Dev Tools cannot account for this additional margin. I have highlighted it and the preceding element in these screenshots to show their margins.

[Preceding widget http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2l6dui7f0zrg9ru/2013-07-11%20at%208.49%20AM.png](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2l6dui7f0zrg9ru/2013-07-11%20at%208.49%20AM.png)
[Recent Posts widget http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/s3okkwwgjma4y09/2013-07-11%20at%208.59%20AM.png](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/s3okkwwgjma4y09/2013-07-11%20at%208.59%20AM.png)

Can anyone tell me what I might need to do to correct this problem? This pushes the widget after the Recent Posts widget to the next row and makes a big mess.

If you want to see the problem, go to http://www.kellyshipe.com/. You'll also see that the row above is perfect with different widgets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elements in the [inline formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting) will take up additional space from carriage returns and white spaces within your HTML. You can simply delete the white space (for whichever elements are inline-block, e.g. `.widget`) or you can alternatively float the widgets so you don't need to mess around with your mark-up.

Comment: This worked like a dream. I floated the elements instead of using inline-block. Now, everything looks just like I wanted it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You need to get rid of the white space in your html between the closing section tag and the opening section tag below (Either delete it OR comment it out).

```
</section>      <section id="recent-posts-2" class="widget widget_recent_entries">
```

Comment: [Other Possible Solutions](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: That was exactly the problem. I ended up going with @adrift's solution of floating the boxes instead. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: @DerekS That's also very helpful. Thanks for sharing it.